# Concat() in Java

Tags: java, string, concatenation, java.util.scanner

I've been trying this program. But I'm not getting the required output.

import java.util.*;

```
class MiscTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i = 10;
        double d = 4.0;
        String s = "Lavante ";

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int j;
        double dd;
        String ss;

        j = scanner.nextInt();
        dd = scanner.nextDouble();
        ss = scanner.next();

        System.out.println("\n" + (i + j));
        System.out.println(d + dd);
        System.out.println(s.concat(ss));

    }
}
```

The input I've given:

[image: Input]

The Output I got:

[image: Output]

I need the whole sentence "Lavante is from Maserati" as output. But, I'm getting only one word from the Second String. Help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the code and not a screenshot.

Comment: Stop posting screenshots of code. Making a screenshot is harder than just copying and pasting of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are hitting enter button after providing input of `double` variable. try code snippet.

```
dd = scan.nextDouble();
ss = scan.nextLine().trim();
if (ss.isEmpty()) {
   ss = scan.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Perfect. As i wanted. Thank you.

Comment: If I am not wrong, you're solving HackerRank daily challenge. right?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `nextLine()` otherwise, `Scanner` stops at the whitespace delimiter using `next()`

Also, after having used `scanner.nextDouble()`, use `scanner.next()` to consume the rest of the characters not read by the previous call, just like below.

```
dd = scanner.nextDouble();
scanner.next();
ss = scanner.nextLine();
```

Comment: If I use nextLine(), It's not letting me to enter the second string. I could enter only int and double.

Comment: @DheerajVuppuluri Ok, read my edit.

Comment: @DheerajVuppuluri check my answer

Comment: @YassinHajaj your snippet will fail if he'll provide inputs with spaces something like this `4 4.0 I am a boy`

Answer (score 3):

[`Scanner#next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) reads up to the first whitespace. If you want to read up to the end of the line, you should use [`nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) instead:

```
ss = scanner.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are currently using the next() Function which is using to take only a String before white spaces

Suppose Input : Hello World
Then If User using next()

Output: Hello

To take the string till the End of line Use nextLine()

Input: Hello World
If user using nextLine()
Output: Hello World

Comment: If I use nextLine(), It's not letting me to enter the second string. I could enter only int and double.

Comment: You need to press enter after entering the string

Comment: Got it. Thank you!